# What would be least configuration of mini mac should be needed to setup PhoneGap development environment?

Tags: cordova, osx-snow-leopard

I am a windows developer and never worked for Mac environment and i just wanted to learn PhoneGap framework and try out and get hands-on some mobile applications. I am looking for cheapest mac machine to try out Phone Gap. Can you let me know what would be least configuration Mac machine that i need to have.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A MacMini would be the cheapest physical machine. You may want to look at the Mac In the Cloud service first though, http://www.macincloud.com/.

Comment: Does it have necessary tools to develop Phone Gap mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn to use PhoneGap does not need a Mac
You can use a Windows PC + Eclipse + Android SDK

Comment: note that he's talking about iOS, still no official way to do that under Windows!